# In a jupyter notebook in Python, what does `%%bash cat Testtext3.txt.*.decodes` do?

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I am wondering what does

```
%%bash 
cat file.txt.*.decodes
```

do?

I got this line from here

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/09_sequence/poetry.ipynb

Here is the original text

```
%%bash  
DECODE_FILE=data/poetry/rumi_leads.txt
cat ${DECODE_FILE}.*.decodes
```

Comment: The double percent sign is a "magic" call to the OS. `cat` is a unix-style command line utility to echo a file to standard out. The asterisk is a glob wild-card on the command line. So this cell calls the OS to echo some text from multiple files probably into the cell.

Comment: It's a linux command, check https://linuxize.com/post/linux-cat-command/

Answer (score 1):

The `%%` starts a "cell magic", which applies to the cell (as opposed to the `%` "line magic" that only affects one line). This particular one changes the language interpreter used for that cell from Python to BASH (the Bourne-Again SHell, used by Unix variants like MacOS and Linux).

You can see documentation for what a magic does by entering it into Jupyter (or IPython) followed by a question mark, like `%%bash?`. Magic is an IPython thing that's not part of Python proper. You'll see it in notebooks, but not in pure Python modules.

The code

```
cat file.txt.*.decodes
```

Uses a glob (the `*`) to get all file names in the current working directory that start with `file.txt.` and end with `.decodes` and uses the `cat` command-line program to print their con**cat**enated contents to stdout. This could certainly have been done in Python, but it would be a bit more verbose.